# how to determine if a variable is a valid class or type in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I validate if a variable is a valid class or type?
I want to validate it before passing it into `isinstance()`
Is there a way other than `try catch`?
I'm using python2

Comment: How would a variable not be of any valid type?

Comment: Isn't that why you would use isinstance?

Comment: say for example if I do isinstance(a, {}), i will get a type error. I want to make sure the second parameter I pass into isinstance is valid.

Comment: use `isinstance(var, type)` since `type` is a `type`. which sounds weird.

Comment: ok! This takes care of the type. Is there a way to determine it is it a valid class then?

Comment: will still work the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regards to my comment:

classes and types are all instances of `type`, so to speak. That's why this will work:

```
>>> class foo():
    pass

>>> t = foo
>>> t
<class '__main__.foo'>
>>> isinstance(t,type)
True
```

EDIT - This works for Python3.x

On Python 2.x the class must be a new-style one (i.e. inherit from `object`)

```
class foo(object):
    pass
```

Comment: I am afraid your answer works on Python3 only. The OP uses Python 2.7

Comment: @Pynchia, that is a fair point that I always forget to take into account. Thank god for the dupe. edited to explicitly state this.

Comment: BTW, the OP talks about variables/instances, I understand, not classes. i.e. `t=foo()`. And in such case, the above solution fails under python 2 (either using old-style or new-style classes. BTW, why are you using the parens in the class declaration?)

Comment: I use new style classes, so this solution seems to work fine even with python2.7

Comment: no, he wants to ensure that the variable is a valid type to pass into as the second argument in `isinstance` so pretty much a type check to do a type check.

Comment: Just doulble checked now: on python 2, it works only provided the class is a new-style one (i.e. `class foo(object):`)

Comment: @Pynchia yeah, I saw that in the dupe post so I figured I could just keep the answer up. and thanks for the edit